Samsung Galaxy Binary Upload Error - Tizen binaries cannot be registered
I am getting the error "Tizen binaries cannot be registered" when i try and upload a wgt file to the Binary Upload for a Watch App in the Samsung Galaxy Store Seller.
I'm not sure if it's something related to my config.xml in my package build or if I have just missed something and generating apps via Tizen studio is not a thing anymore?
I have used Tizen studio and developed a wearable Web Application. I used the Certificate Manager to create a certificate and then built the package. I am using the built wgt file to upload to my Samsung Developer App submission when I get this error.
I am new to Tizen and Samsung so I'm not sure what information i have not provided that might be useful.

Based on this https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-tizen/notice.html
They are not allowing any new Tizen apps for their wearable devices on the galaxy store.

Thanks! Do you know what the best method of developing a samsung watch app would be then? I was using Tizen Studio and getting this error.
I then tried galaxy watch studio and couldn't generate a distribute certificate. I also read somewhere that was deprecated as well.

@C-Bertram their software is broken... I created a certificate with the Tizen Cert Manager, and then had to go into VS extension settings and then switch it to manual and it worked

Thank you! Is Galaxy Watch studio the best thing to use? I'm not trying to create a watch face but an app and then load it into the samsung seller store. Do you know the best way to create an eligible binary?

@C-Bertram I don't think samsung is accepting any tizen apps for watches anymore (watch faces as well), if I am not mistaken
